# AspectJ- Calling the aspect function from another project throws NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint

Tags: java, logging, aspectj, maven-surefire-plugin, aspectj-maven-plugin

**Requirement:** - We have a Java `methodA` in `ProjectA`. This `methodA` is used across different teams by adding JAR dependencies to their POMs. We want to collect some metrics, like which teams are calling `methodA`.

**Idea:** I am exploring using AspectJ in my non-Spring project.

**Problem:** In `ProjectB`, we added the `ProjectA` dependency and called `methodA`, but ended up getting the error below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Signature
```

**Project A:**

`src/main/javaAspectClass.java` has around and pointcut on method to be monitored

```java
@Around("execution(* com.aspectj.CommonClass.*(..))")
public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint point) throws Throwable {
  System.out.println("Function monitored");
}
```

`src/main/java/com/aspectj/CommonClass/methodA`

`pom.xml`: Dependencies added are `aspectjrt`, `aspectjweaver` and Surefire plugin

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.9</version>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>-XX:-UseSplitVerifier</argLine>
    <argLine>-javaagent:C:\Users\**\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.13\aspectjweaver-1.8.13.jar</argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and aspectj-maven-plugin

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
  <configuration>
    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <!-- IMPORTANT -->
      <phase>process-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>test-compile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
      <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

**Project B:**

`pom.xml` has dependency of `ProjectA`

In a test class, I am calling `methodA` of `ProjectA`, but getting the error below:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Signature
```

Comment: I completely rephrased and reformatted your question, which was quite a lot of work. Please try to be more careful when using code formatting and other formatting elements. I hope you do not mind that I also changed the wording a bit. 

Comment: Thankyou. Looking forward for the suggestion from experts in resolving this issue.

Comment: Does project A declare a dependency on `aspectjrt`? Just configuring the compiler correctly, is only part of the deal. You also need the AspectJ runtime, if you want to run an aspect-enhanced application.

Comment: @kriegaex Yes project A pom has **aspectjrt** dependency. I believe aspectjrt is the runtime dependency you are referring ?   And I have set LWT in project A .

Comment: This is not a discussion forum, so let us stop discussing theoretical questions. I dislike guessing, I much prefer analysing facts. Please publish a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally on GitHub. Then I can take a look tomorrow.

Comment: @kriegaex  Sure will send the GitHub link. I believe I just answered to your question in the comment.

Comment: Your answer is exactly what triggered me asking for an MCVE, because (a) I cannot debug  prose and (b) you said you use both AspectJ Maven (i.e. compile-time weaving) and LTW in a multi-module Maven project. This is too complex to simply answer correctly, just looking at the snippets in your question. Too many moving parts, too much missing information. I would not have asked for the MCVE if I knew the solution already. I am not doing this in order to bug you but to help you.

Comment: BTW, why are you using LTW? CTW would be easier to configure, both for testing and during application runtime. Can you explain the rationale for using LTW? There are many valid use cases, of course. I simply wannt to understand why you are doing this. Maybe a simpler solution would also cater to your needs.